# Interpreting Decision Tree in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I built a Decision Tree in python and I am struggling to interpret it. The tree look like as picture below.

[image]

This a Churn model result. I want to know how can I interpret the following:

```
  1. Number of children at home <=3.5  (Integer)
  2. MaritalStatus_M <= 0.5  (M- Married in here and was a binary. I was expecting either MaritalStatus_M=0 or =1)
  3. Sales Reason_Price<=0.5 (Binary. I was expecting either Sales Reason_Price=0 or =1)
  4. Tenure_Months<= 0.5 (Integer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some internal reasons why split decisions in trees prefer a `<=` relation (rather than equality, even if the latter might seem to make more sense for a human reader), but such *representation* details should not pose any difficulty in the **interpretation**, which is what you are asking about here.

So, practically speaking:

1. `children <= 3.5` means `less than four children` (assuming variable is integer)
2. `MaritalStatus_M <= 0.5` for a binary variable means `MaritalStatus_M==0` (i.e. `not married`)
3. `Sales Reason_Price<=0.5` for a binary variable means `Sales Reason_Price==0`
4. `Tenure_Months<= 0.5` means `Tenure_Months==0` (assuming variable is integer)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and Tenure_months is integer. Once I got "Tenure_Months<=20.6179". Would that be interpreted as "Tenure_Months==20 and less"?

Comment: @L.G. yes, it should be `Tenure_Months < 21` or `Tenure_Months <= 20` (which translate to the same thing)

Comment: how would I interpret if one variable appear more than once in a branch? in the picture it is MIN_TXN_VALUE, in orange color, with the class Not_Churn. Please read MIN_TXN_VALUE as minimum transaction value

Comment: @L.G. Pls try to apply some common sense when reading the tree (trees are supposedly especially good for this). Cannot see what you mean - the only orange `Not_churn` leaf I can see is about `MAX_TXN_VALUE`, not `MIN`; the branch starting from `MIN_TXN_VALUE <= 21.735` for `True` continues to `MIN_TXN_VALUE <= 4.49` (which is not a contradiction), which for `True` ends up to `MAX_TXN_VALUE <= 4.49`, which is again not in contradiction with the previous nodes